# Error Opening Secondary Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF. I have a window named `NewWindow.xaml`, and I want it to open when the user presses a button in a separate Window. This is what I have:

```
    private void Button(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;

        NewWindow.Show();
    }
```

Although, it gives me an error and says I can simplify it. Then, it doesn't do anything. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of your code in that method:

```
NewWindow yourInstanceOfTheNewWindow = new NewWindow();
yourInstanceOfTheNewWindow.Show();
```

Click [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/898/show-a-window-in-wpf.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms748948(v=vs.110).aspx) for more Information.

Comment: Do I have to set the New Window class as an Instance of the original window, like this:

Comment: ` public class NewWindow : Original Window`